# SQL Server Management Studio 11 Getting data from results

Tags: sql, csv, spreadsheet, google-docs

I ran a query but now I want to get the data from the query into a spreadsheet but when I select the option 'copy with headers' and I attempt to paste it into a spreadsheet the data gets all messed up; I think it's an issue with the delimiters?

So when I try to save the file as a csv for some reason open office always opens it with open-calc and when I try to upload it onto google docs it fails.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on File -> Save Results As.  Pick a location, name and extension of your choice.  The output will be ASCII text.  Use a text editor to change delimiters to suit your spreadsheet.

I only have MS Excel available.  If I open it and then click File -> Open and select the SMSS output file, it will start an import wizard allowing me to specify delimiter etc.  Perhaps your spreadsheet tool can do something similar.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I tried that but I get an issue where randomly a value is out of place and when in the results section it's all in the correct place. I'm really confused to why this happens

Comment: That would suggest your data contains whatever the delimiter is.  Try querying each textual column one-at-a-time for the delimiter.

Comment: It turns out an old developer had accidentally inputted data in the wrong fields! I don't know who's sillier him/her or me for not verifying the data earlier. Thanks for your help :)!